# Last edittext not shown above the keyboard in android

Tags: android

when i click on the edit text field key board appear and all my edit text fields  move above the key board except the last one what can be the problem?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_color">
   <TextView

     android:id="@+id/formReg"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:text="@string/register_form"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"
     android:textStyle="normal"
     android:textSize="20sp" /> 
   <View 
       android:id="@+id/h_line"
     android:background="#ffffff" 
     android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="0.5dip"
     android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
     android:layout_below="@id/formReg"
      />
     <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="640dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/formReg"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background_color"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="290dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounder_edittext"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="@string/name_hint"
                android:ems="18"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" >

             <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
            <EditText
                 android:id="@+id/user_name"
                 android:layout_width="290dp"
                 android:layout_height="40dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/rounder_edittext"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                 android:hint="@string/user_name_hint"
                 android:ems="10"
                 android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                 android:inputType="text" >

            </EditText>

            <EditText
                 android:id="@+id/Password"
                 android:layout_width="290dp"
                 android:layout_height="40dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/rounder_edittext"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                 android:hint="@string/password_hint"
                 android:ems="12"
                 android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                 android:inputType="textPassword" />

            <EditText
                 android:id="@+id/email_address"
                 android:layout_width="290dp"
                 android:layout_height="40dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/rounder_edittext"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                 android:hint="@string/email_hint"
                 android:ems="25"
                 android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                 android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
            <Spinner
                 android:id="@+id/country"
                 android:layout_width="290dp"
                 android:layout_height="40dp" 
                 android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/rounder_edittext"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             />
            <LinearLayout 

                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                 android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
             >
             <EditText
                android:id="@+id/country_code"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounder_edittext"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/country_code_hint"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:inputType="phone"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/phone_number"
                android:layout_width="215dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounder_edittext"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:hint="@string/phone_hint"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:inputType="phone" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <EditText
                 android:id="@+id/email_address"
                 android:layout_width="290dp"
                 android:layout_height="40dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/rounder_edittext"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                 android:hint="@string/email_hint"
                 android:ems="25"
                 android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                 android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <include
        android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
        layout="@layout/footer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ihave changed the no of fileds but always the last one not show above the key board

Comment: I think the problem is your Relative layout. either you have not set property correctly like `android:layout_below` and `android:layout_above`or try to change layout to linerlayout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this in the manifest of your application

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize
```

Answer (score 0):

Then try this tutorial,this ll help you

http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html

Answer (score 0):

replace your xml code with this....its work...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/container"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@color/background_color"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/formReg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/register_form"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

  <View
    android:id="@+id/h_line"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/formReg"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="#000000" />

 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollablContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_color"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounder_edittext"
            android:ems="18"
            android:hint="@string/name_hint"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" >
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounder_edittext"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/user_name_hint"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" >
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Password"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounder_edittext"
            android:ems="12"
            android:hint="@string/password_hint"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email_address"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounder_edittext"
            android:ems="25"
            android:hint="@string/email_hint"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/country"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounder_edittext" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/country_code"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/rounder_edittext"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/country_code_hint"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/phone_number"
                android:layout_width="215dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:ems="10"
                 android:background="@drawable/rounder_edittext"
                    android:hint="@string/phone_hint"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email_address"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="25"
             android:background="@drawable/rounder_edittext"
            android:hint="@string/email_hint"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>

 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footerView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->

    <include layout="@layout/footer" />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```